# AWS Lambda not making HTTP POST request as expected

Tags: aws-lambda, discord

Can someone explain to me why I am unable to make a post request from AWS Lambda to my Discord webhook using the code below?

```js
import * as p from 'phin'

import * as data from './json/test.json'
import {
  url
} from './json/webhook.json'
import {
  Context,
  Event
} from './types'

const config = {
  url,
  method: "POST",
  data,
}

export async function handler(event: Event, context: Context) {
  const response = await p(config)
  return response.body
}
```

The code works perfectly locally on my own computer. The message shows up on my Discord channel. And is also executes on AWS. Here is the execution result:

```
Response:
{
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    123,
    34,
    109,
    101,
    115,
    115,
    ...
  ]
}

Request ID:
"901a641a-e793-4750-8be0-a2dd96f8e883"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 901a641a-e793-4750-8be0-a2dd96f8e883 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 901a641a-e793-4750-8be0-a2dd96f8e883
REPORT RequestId: 901a641a-e793-4750-8be0-a2dd96f8e883  Duration: 301.42 ms Billed Duration: 302 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB
```

Only problem: nothing happens in Discord! What am I missing? :)

Comment: The lambda output doesn't really give you any hints, are you capturing any errors/exceptions? If not that might be a good start, just print them to stdout do that they show up in the lambda log.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. The JSON sent to Discord (for whatever reason) different when using Lambda compared to locally. From lambda the data was put into a property "default", so the post request would look like this:

```
{
  "default": {
    // my data
  }
}
```

And since this does not conform with Discord, nothing would show up.

Exactly where in the process the data winded up in a "default" property, I am not sure.